# How to import freebase full data-dump file N-Triples UTF8 to neo4j

Tags: java, php, python, neo4j, freebase

I downloaded **[freebase data-dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) in RDF data is serialized using the N-Triples format, encoded as UTF-8** text and compressed with Gzip. I would like to **import it to Neo4j**.

There are a lot of java source codes without documentation and with too much dependencies.
Even manuals on official website are linking to broken pages or github repositories without documentation at all. I understand that Neo4j isn't a triple store, I would like to create a graph.

**How to create database from freebase full data dump file in neo4j?**

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it ?

Comment: John, unfortunately till now it's only way to create your own import/parser script :( haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of:

[Import RDF (XML or Turtle) into Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676485/import-rdf-xml-or-turtle-into-neo4j)

As an addendum to the accepted response there, if you choose to write a custom importer, have a look at the Neo4j Batch Importer, which allows fast offline bulk import into Neo4j.

Comment: May be it's reopening of that question, but it doesn't speaks about broken data.

In addition:
1. Neo4j Linked Data leads to broken link and github project without any documentation.
2. "importing DBPedia dumps, your situation should be analogous" - so I understand no one did it before and there is no direct way?
3. Why that answer was accepted? It just redirects you to manuals that are not well documented or missing.

Comment: Sorry about the broken link, I've asked our webadmins to pull it down. I'm afraid there is no good official tooling from Neo Tech to do this, so you'll have to either write tooling manually that reads the data and loads it using the batch inserter, or you'll need to contact the authors of the undocumented projects and ask for hints. I'm sorry I can't be of more help than that :(

Comment: Thank you for response, at least some one interested :)
 I have tried a lot of java source codes including Batch-importer and freebase-neo4j-importer by young-zhang. All those scripts are mess  with lots of dependencies and without any explanations.